# Error from a SQL Server stored procedure where clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am completely out of my depth with this one, if anybody can help me I would greatly appreciate it.

Another programmer wrote the below stored procedure. I need a simple modification to it. It currently queries the entire database. I need to limit it to records created after a certain date. I would like to have a where that acts on the field stop_details.record_created > "9/1/18'

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StopVisitsByCustomer]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CUSTOMERNAMES AS VARCHAR(MAX), -- TO FETCH THE UNIQUE CUSTOMER NAME FOR THE PIVOTING
            @SQLQRY AS VARCHAR(MAX) -- FOR HOLDING DYNAMIC SQL

    SELECT @CUSTOMERNAMES = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CUSTOMER_NAME)
                                   FROM CUSTOMERS
                                   GROUP BY CUSTOMER_NAME
                                   ORDER BY CUSTOMER_NAME
                                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

    -- DYNAMIC SQL FOR THE PIVOT QUERY TO RETURN THE DETAILS IN THE DESIRED FORMAT
    SET @SQLQRY = 'SELECT 
                       CON_NAME AS ConName,
                       CON_ADDRESS1 AS Address1,
                       CON_ADDRESS2 AS Address2,
                       CON_CITY AS City,
                       CON_STATE AS State,
                       CON_ZIP AS Zip, ' + @CUSTOMERNAMES + ' 
                   FROM 
                       (SELECT  
                            CON_NAME,
                            CON_ADDRESS1,
                            CON_ADDRESS2,
                            CON_CITY,
                            CON_STATE,
                            CON_ZIP,
                            CUSTOMER_ID, 
                            CUSTOMER_NAME
                        FROM 
                            STOP_DETAILS
                        INNER JOIN
                            CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = STOP_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_ID) Stops
            PIVOT 
                (COUNT(CUSTOMER_NAME)
                 FOR CUSTOMER_NAME in (' + @CUSTOMERNAMES + ')
                ) Customers'

    -- EXECUTE THE DYNAMIC SQL FOR GIVING THE OUTPUT
    EXECUTE(@SQLQRY);
END
```

I have tried putting the where clause several places but keep getting an error.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: ***WHAT*** error are you getting? Remember: we cannot see and read your screen - nor can we read your mind (yet) - you need to **SHOW US** to have any chance of being able to help you

Comment: it will be easier for you to help yourself and also others to help you if you can do a `PRINT @SQLQRY` before you execute it. And also please post the query here

Comment: Do you see the table STOP_DETAILS mentioned anywhere? Yes - it's part of the derived table names stops. Now add a where clause to that query with the condition you wrote. Test it, report back with any errors. NB - use single quotes to delimit strings and use the format YYYMMDD as the format for a date literal. Another NB - it is almost 20 years since Y2K - STOP using 2 digit years!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your request, it appears that you would add your `WHERE` after the `INNER JOIN`. Please also note that because it is a dynamic query, you'll have to double your quotes:

```
INNER JOIN  CUSTOMERS ON CUSTOMERS.ID = STOP_DETAILS.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE stop_details.record_created > ''2018-09-01'') Stops
```

Comment: Thank you -- this is exactly what I was doing but I was using a " vs two single quotes.  Changed it to how you have it and it work.